# How to export a Pandas dataframe to Excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Python code which produces data, I'd like to export it to a CSV when run, rather than just printing results into the terminal. I've attempted this with Pandas ExcelWriter but my code below is bringing back the error:

```
<pandas.io.excel._XlsxWriter object at 0x00000000085F7358>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-6c7cf0bb1fd6> in <module>()
     25         # export to CSV
     26         writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
---> 27         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
     28         writer.save()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for i in range(1, 300):
    url = "xxx=%s" % i

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-block__info')
    for item in items:
        product = item.find('span', class_='short_desc').text
        stock = item.find('span', class_='count_product_stock hidden').text
        brand = item.find('h4', class_='brand').text
        price = item.find('span', class_='selling_price').text

        # print (brand, product, stock, price)

        # group all the data togeather into a dataframe
        df = {'Brand': brand, 'Product': product, 'Stock': stock, 'Price': price}
        print(data)

        # export to CSV
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()
```

Can anyone see the problem here that stopping the export?

Comment: Dictionaries (which `df` is) don't have a `to_excel` method, dataframes do.

Comment: Thank you both - I read that question before, but it's taken a second read through to realize that this is my problem too. However, I don't understand how I can fix this from reading the response - would you be able to provide a more 'newbie' explanation?

Comment: you don't have a dataframe and you need to create one.